# Amalgamated free-product of semigroups (definition)

Tags: ct.category-theory, semigroups-and-monoids, universal-algebra, definitions

I am self-studying some concepts including the title one. I reached the definition of an amalgamated free-product ${S_1}{*_U}S_2$ where $[S_1, S_2; U, w_1,w_2]$ is an amalgam of semigroups. Let $S_1=\langle G_{S_1}|R_{S_1}\rangle$, $S_2=\langle G_{S_2}|R_{S_2}\rangle$ and $U$ is an embeddable semigroup under monomorphisms $w_i:U\to S_i$. Does the following describe the structure of ${S_1}{*_U}S_2$ in a right way?

$${S_1}{*_U}S_2=\langle G_{S_1}\cup G_{S_2} |R_{S_1}\cup R_{S_2}, w_1(u)=w_2(u), u\in U\rangle$$

Thanks for your time. I am checking my own understanding.

Comment: Aside from a typo (the second $G_{S_1}$ in the definition of $S_1 \ast_U S_2$ should be $G_{S_2}$), this seems to be literally the definition of the amalgamated product, as long as you arrange that $G_{S_1}$ and $G_{S_2}$ are disjoint.  What is the question?

Comment: One should be aware of Mark Sapir's amazing result that an amalgamated free product of finite semigroups can have undecidable word problem. So the presentation is more or less what you can say.

Comment: @LSpice: thanks for your time and the attention. I was just to check if that presentation describes the title or not. Your comment says this is for amalgamated products not the free one. Am I right? Regards.

Comment: @LSpice In view of the "category-theory" tag, I suppose "literally the definition" would be the universal property of the pushout. I'd prefer that definition myself, partly on aesthetic grounds and partly because, if one uses the presentation as a definition, then one needs to check that the result is unchanged (up to isomorphism) if one uses different presentations for $S_1$ and $S_2$.

Comment: @‍BabakS., I'm no group theorist, but I've always used "free product" only for the case $U = 1$, and "amalgamated product" (although some people say "amalgamated free product") for the general case.  Anyway, indeed what you've written is a correct presentation for that object, whatever it's called.  @AndreasBlass, I guess it's always hard to decide what's the definition and what's the theorem (hence the Bourbaki-style "théorème-définition")—existence questions might arise—but I agree with you that one should regard the essential point as the universal property, not this ugly definition.